# C# winforms best place where to check if user logged

Tags: c#, winforms

Guys in my winforms desktop application i have user logging system. Am not sure where to set logic to check if user is logged or not. If is logged show main window or if not logged show login form.

First i try to avoid using database for logging because winforms does not support sessions. I crate static `User` class where i store super_admin credentials and that is enough for this app.

So my first try is to set everything in main before mainWindow form is showed:

**Program.cs**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    if (!User.IsLogged)
    {
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }

    Application.Run(new Login());         
}
```

Or is better to set this inside `MainWindow` form inside constructor or in `Load`? Or Maybe inside static `MainWindow` constuctor? MainWindow is mdi!

So can you suggest me what is better way?

Here is static (User.cs):

```
private static string superAdminUsername = "admin";
private static string superAdminPassword = "123";


public static bool IsLogged
{
    get
    {
        return isLogged;
    }
    set
    {
        isLogged = value;
    }
}

public static bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    if (username == superAdminUsername && password == superAdminPassword)
    {
        isLogged = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: "logged" means something totally different from "logged in". Also, hardcoding a password into the app in plaintext is just a recipe to get hacked.

Comment: If I were doing this, I would create a base form that all forms in your project inherit from and when it loads (OnShown or PerformLayout) check to see if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, display a blocking modal dialog that requires the user to log in.

Comment: @mason am quote myself `I crate static User class where i store super_admin credentials and that is enough for this app.` . @AWinkle base form is `MainWindow` he is MID and all other forms is loaded inside that form in new tab

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a matter of opinion, but as long as there is no sensitive info being displayed, I would create the main window, and then request the login using a new login window and loginWindow.ShowDialog() in the Load event handler of the main window so that it blocks the thread until the user logs in.  That way the user can see the application window, but will have a popup dialog that they must complete before they can do anything useful.  Once the loginWindow closes, you can try to get the login name that was used, and populate the rest of the data if the login succeeded, or prompt the user and close the application if the login was incorrect.  (This assumes that the login window contains the logic to verify the user name and password, and that the user MUST be logged in to use the application - if this is incorrect, modify the approach accordingly.)

With that approach, you can assume the user is logged in if they are using the program, and instead of storing an "IsLoggedIn" bool, you could store the user name instead, which would be useful for applying permissions.

If the user can do basic things without logging in, then I would just start the program, and then have a "Login" button that creates the login window.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider showing the login form as a dialog till the user is authenticated, aborting if the user gives up:

```
while (!User.IsLoggedIn)
{
    string user;
    string pass;
    if (Login.Show(out user, out pass) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        User.Authenticate(user, pass);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox("Unable to log in!");
        break;
    }
}

if (User.IsLoggedIn)
{
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

And the Login form looks something like this:

```
class Login : Form
{
    TextBox User;
    TextBox Pass;
    public Login()
    {
        User = new TextBox();
        User.Bounds = new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 20);
        Controls.Add(User);

        Pass = new TextBox();
        Pass.Bounds = new Rectangle(5, 25, 100, 20);
        Controls.Add(Pass);

        Button ok = new Button();
        ok.Text = "OK";
        ok.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        ok.Bounds = new Rectangle(5, 50, 100, 20);
        Controls.Add(ok);

        Text = "Login";
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(out string user, out string pass)
    {
        Login self = new Login();
        DialogResult ret = self.ShowDialog();
        user = self.User.Text;
        pass = self.Pass.Text;
        return ret;
    }
}
```